# How to calculate Accuracy of this model

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nltk

I am trying to text classification using nltk.
This is for Ipython I run successfully code.
Please help me to find out accuracy of this model also training and testing rate.

```
# use natural language toolkit
import nltk
from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
import os
import json
import datetime
stemmer = LancasterStemmer()

import pandas as pd
import json


    with open('/content/text_emotion1.json') as f:
      training_data = json.load(f)

    print(training_data)

words = []
classes = []
documents = []
ignore_words = ['?']
# loop through each sentence in our training data
for pattern in training_data:
    # tokenize each word in the sentence
    w = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern['Sentence'])
    # add to our words list
    words.extend(w)
    # add to documents in our corpus
    documents.append((w, pattern['Class']))
    # add to our classes list
    if pattern['Class'] not in classes:
        classes.append(pattern['Class'])

# stem and lower each word and remove duplicates
words = [stemmer.stem(w.lower()) for w in words if w not in ignore_words]
words = list(set(words))

# remove duplicates
classes = list(set(classes))

print (len(documents), "documents")
print (len(classes), "classes", classes)
print (len(words), "unique stemmed words", words)




# create our training data
training = []
output = []
# create an empty array for our output
output_empty = [0] * len(classes)

# training set, bag of words for each sentence
for doc in documents:
    # initialize our bag of words
    bag = []
    # list of tokenized words for the pattern
    pattern_words = doc[0]
    # stem each word
    pattern_words = [stemmer.stem(word.lower()) for word in pattern_words]
    # create our bag of words array
    for w in words:
        bag.append(1) if w in pattern_words else bag.append(0)

    training.append(bag)
    # output is a '0' for each tag and '1' for current tag
    output_row = list(output_empty)
    output_row[classes.index(doc[1])] = 1
    output.append(output_row)

# sample training/output
i = 0
w = documents[i][0]
print ([stemmer.stem(word.lower()) for word in w])
print (training[i])
print (output[i])



import numpy as np
import time

# compute sigmoid nonlinearity
def sigmoid(x):
    output = 1/(1+np.exp(-x))
    return output

# convert output of sigmoid function to its derivative
def sigmoid_output_to_derivative(output):
    return output*(1-output)

def clean_up_sentence(sentence):
    # tokenize the pattern
    sentence_words = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
    # stem each word
    sentence_words = [stemmer.stem(word.lower()) for word in sentence_words]
    return sentence_words

# return bag of words array: 0 or 1 for each word in the bag that exists in the sentence
def bow(sentence, words, show_details=False):
    # tokenize the pattern
    sentence_words = clean_up_sentence(sentence)
    # bag of words
    bag = [0]*len(words)  
    for s in sentence_words:
        for i,w in enumerate(words):
            if w == s: 
                bag[i] = 1
                if show_details:
                    print ("found in bag: %s" % w)

    return(np.array(bag))

def think(sentence, show_details=False):
    x = bow(sentence.lower(), words, show_details)
    if show_details:
        print ("sentence:", sentence, "\n bow:", x)
    # input layer is our bag of words
    l0 = x
    # matrix multiplication of input and hidden layer
    l1 = sigmoid(np.dot(l0, synapse_0))
    # output layer
    l2 = sigmoid(np.dot(l1, synapse_1))
    return l2



def train(X, y, hidden_neurons=10, alpha=1, epochs=50000, dropout=False, dropout_percent=0.5):

    print ("Training with %s neurons, alpha:%s, dropout:%s %s" % (hidden_neurons, str(alpha), dropout, dropout_percent if dropout else '') )
    print ("Input matrix: %sx%s    Output matrix: %sx%s" % (len(X),len(X[0]),1, len(classes)) )
    np.random.seed(1)

    last_mean_error = 1
    # randomly initialize our weights with mean 0
    synapse_0 = 2*np.random.random((len(X[0]), hidden_neurons)) - 1
    synapse_1 = 2*np.random.random((hidden_neurons, len(classes))) - 1

    prev_synapse_0_weight_update = np.zeros_like(synapse_0)
    prev_synapse_1_weight_update = np.zeros_like(synapse_1)

    synapse_0_direction_count = np.zeros_like(synapse_0)
    synapse_1_direction_count = np.zeros_like(synapse_1)

    for j in iter(range(epochs+1)):

        # Feed forward through layers 0, 1, and 2
        layer_0 = X
        layer_1 = sigmoid(np.dot(layer_0, synapse_0))

        if(dropout):
            layer_1 *= np.random.binomial([np.ones((len(X),hidden_neurons))],1-dropout_percent)[0] * (1.0/(1-dropout_percent))

        layer_2 = sigmoid(np.dot(layer_1, synapse_1))

        # how much did we miss the target value?
        layer_2_error = y - layer_2

        if (j% 10000) == 0 and j > 5000:
            # if this 10k iteration's error is greater than the last iteration, break out
            if np.mean(np.abs(layer_2_error)) < last_mean_error:
                print ("delta after "+str(j)+" iterations:" + str(np.mean(np.abs(layer_2_error))) )
                last_mean_error = np.mean(np.abs(layer_2_error))
            else:
                print ("break:", np.mean(np.abs(layer_2_error)), ">", last_mean_error )
                break

        # in what direction is the target value?
        # were we really sure? if so, don't change too much.
        layer_2_delta = layer_2_error * sigmoid_output_to_derivative(layer_2)

        # how much did each l1 value contribute to the l2 error (according to the weights)?
        layer_1_error = layer_2_delta.dot(synapse_1.T)

        # in what direction is the target l1?
        # were we really sure? if so, don't change too much.
        layer_1_delta = layer_1_error * sigmoid_output_to_derivative(layer_1)

        synapse_1_weight_update = (layer_1.T.dot(layer_2_delta))
        synapse_0_weight_update = (layer_0.T.dot(layer_1_delta))

        if(j > 0):
            synapse_0_direction_count += np.abs(((synapse_0_weight_update > 0)+0) - ((prev_synapse_0_weight_update > 0) + 0))
            synapse_1_direction_count += np.abs(((synapse_1_weight_update > 0)+0) - ((prev_synapse_1_weight_update > 0) + 0))        

        synapse_1 += alpha * synapse_1_weight_update
        synapse_0 += alpha * synapse_0_weight_update

        prev_synapse_0_weight_update = synapse_0_weight_update
        prev_synapse_1_weight_update = synapse_1_weight_update

    now = datetime.datetime.now()

    # persist synapses
    synapse = {'synapse0': synapse_0.tolist(), 'synapse1': synapse_1.tolist(),
               'datetime': now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"),
               'words': words,
               'classes': classes
              }
    synapse_file = "synapses1.json"

    with open(synapse_file, 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(synapse, outfile, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
    print ("saved synapses to:", synapse_file)

X = np.array(training)
y = np.array(output)

start_time = time.time()

train(X, y, hidden_neurons=20, alpha=0.1, epochs=100000, dropout=False, dropout_percent=0.2)

elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
print ("processing time:", elapsed_time, "seconds")


# probability threshold

ERROR_THRESHOLD = 0.2

# load our calculated synapse values

synapse_file = 'synapses1.json' 

with open(synapse_file) as data_file: 

    synapse = json.load(data_file) 

    synapse_0 = np.asarray(synapse['synapse0']) 

    synapse_1 = np.asarray(synapse['synapse1'])

​

def classify(sentence, show_details=False):

    results = think(sentence, show_details)

​

    results = [[i,r] for i,r in enumerate(results) if r>ERROR_THRESHOLD ] 

    results.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True) 

    return_results =[[classes[r[0]],r[1]] for r in results]

    print ("%s \n classification: %s" % (sentence, return_results))

    return return_results

​

classify("Thanks for listening to my ideas")

classify("Happy that my input counts.")

classify("The organisation cares for us. ")

classify("i admire your work")

classify("Happy to see the recognition.")

classify("I understand your feelings.")

classify("you done great job.")

classify("You've been so generous, and I'd like to show my appreciation by cooking a meal for you.")

print()

classify("re", show_details=True)
```

I tried this code for calculating accuracy, is it correct?

```
print(nltk.classify.accuracy(train,y))
```

I got this output that is correct but how can I calculate accuracy?

```
Thanks for listening to my ideas 
 classification: [[u'Inclusion', 0.9982807293621314]]
Happy that my input counts. 
 classification: [[u'Inclusion', 0.9985216430632661]]
The organisation cares for us.  
 classification: [[u'Affection', 0.9992941560542158]]
i admire your work 
 classification: [[u'Appreciation', 0.999991946064935]]
Happy to see the recognition. 
 classification: [[u'Appreciation', 0.9984700442334942]]
I understand your feelings. 
 classification: [[u'Appreciation', 0.2621556490249265]]
you done great job. 
 classification: [[u'Appreciation', 0.9942391918360257]]
You've been so generous, and I'd like to show my appreciation by cooking a meal for you. 
 classification: [[u'Appreciation', 0.9892466429493599]]
```

Comment: you need to split your training_data into train and test data. Then build the model using only train data and check model performance on test data.

Comment: I have this data so can you help me with code while i am splitting data it shows error.

Comment: what error you got?